# Setting corner radius on UIDatePicker with a background color

Tags: objective-c, ios7, calayer, uidatepicker, cornerradius

I have a `UIDatePicker` in my view and have set the background color of the `UIDatePicker`:

```
self.datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
self.datePicker.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

This successfully puts a background behind the `UIDatePicker` (*which in iOS7 is essentially transparent*) but fails to make the rounded corners for the background that I am looking for (*I do this same thing for an image on the screen and it works perfectly*).
It seems that the corner radius doesn't affect the background color.
Is there a way to fix this problem by setting a corner radius for the background color (or any another solution).

The reason I want to do this is because the ordinary `UIDatePicker` looks awkward in the view I have constructed and looks much better with a background color.
However, all the other items in the view have rounded corners and I want the `UIDatePicker` to match them.

Thanks.

Comment: taking a screenshot (_for such questions_) is always beneficial

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to add  `layer.masksToBounds=YES;`

Try this,

```
self.datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
self.datePicker.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.datePicker.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

**UIBuilder Swift 5 solution:**

See picture, it's the same as @ToseefKhiji's solution but even easier to execute for fans of UIBuilder controls.

[image]

This is how it comes out (I have added other features to the picker programmatically, such as borderWidth, color, etc...)

[image]

UIBuilder is underappreciated by Swift/iOS coders as everyone has rushed to SwiftUI as the new new thing.